# Como generar y descargar CSV con PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpspreadsheet

estoy trabajando con mvc para generando un SCV.
Para generar el documento primero coloco los rangos de fechas en sweetalert para hacer una consulta  y despues las mando en un ajax para hacer un post y mandar las fechas en el documento **generarCsv.php** en donde obtengo los resultados y creo un forecha para recorrer el array asociativo

en el documento generarCsv.php creo el metodo public function generarCSV();
para crear el csv y descargarlo

y en el ajax quiero mostrar un boton que diga descragar

[codigo para generar el CSV](https://github.com/jesusasc/GeneraryDescargarCSV.git)

espero de su ayuda soy nuevo en esto :(

Comment: Hola. No se admiten proyectos enteros o código alojado externamente. Tu pregunta debe contener el fragmento de código donde tienes el problema, de lo contrario nos veremos obligados a analizar todo tu código y luego intentar adivinar la lógica y luego encontrar el problema. Pulsa en [edit] y mejora la pregunta poniendo un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya hice la modificación resumí mi código

Comment: Últimamente he trabajado con esa biblioteca, podrías colocar algunos fragmentos de código, yo logre que tras un `<input>` en un form se descargue un .xlsx, pero se ocupa que desarrolles más tu problema

Comment: hola @LuisJairJuarezSanchez mi código se encuentra en la parte de  código para generar el CSV pero te paso el link de mi repositorio https://github.com/jesusasc/GeneraryDescargarCSV.git ya que intente colocar en esta plataforma pero no me permitia colocar codigo html y no podia hacer la pregunta, opte en colocarlo en un repositorio

Answer (score 0):

En la parte de tu boton

```
$button = '<a href="$Excel_writer" class="btn btn-primary disabled" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="true">Descargar</a>';
```

Intenta hacer el `href` dirigido a `generarCSV.php` de la siguiente manera:

```
$button = '<a href="generarCSV.php" class="btn btn-primary disabled" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="true">Descargar</a>';
```

En teoria deberia recargar todas las instrucciones e indicar la descarga

Otra cosa que descubrí trabajando con esa biblioteca es que después del `output` no es recomendable colocar más líneas de código, se puede convertir en un dolor de cabeza, inténtalo y me cuentas

Comment: bueno el error que me mostraba que era `POS https://localhos/proyecto/Error/Index net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` ya no me muestra solo me dice que **La pagina que buscas no existe** ya que estoy trabanjando en mvc cabe mecionar que en el primer ajax que no coloque me muestra de manera dinamica las filas de la tabla ahora solo me muestra La pagina que buscas no existe

Comment: agregue el codigo de la maquetacion de mi tabla en que te comente anterior mente en el documento ajax.js